# How to rename phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

To access database I use localhost/phpmyadmin now I want to rename phpmyadmin i.e. I want to access database typing localhost/phpmyadmin_renamed. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

On your httpd.conf file find `<Ifmodule alias_module>` that must contains something like `Alias /phpmyadmin "${path}/phpmyadmin"`

Now, change it to:

`Alias /phpmyadmin_renamed "${path}/phpmyadmin"`

Note: `"$(path)/phpmyadmin"` can be anything else depending upon your server.

**Alternative Approach:**

Or, You can just download phpmyadmin and extract to phpmyadmin_renamed.